# In vuejs application having firebase error

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am getting errors while running a Vue project. Not sure what it is, the screen coming up as blank. with the following error, image attached.

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... index.esm.js?2591:56  It
> looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
> When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only
> import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
> (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
> etc):
>
> CommonJS Modules: const firebase = require('firebase/app');
> require('firebase/');
>
> ES Modules: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import
> 'firebase/';
>
> Typescript: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import
> 'firebase/';
>
> eval @ index.esm.js?2591:56 firebaseService.js?bb96:15 Uncaught
> TypeError: this.firebaseLib.initializeApp is not a function at new
> FirebaseService (firebaseService.js?bb96:15) at useFirebase
> (useFirebase.js?0b68:4) at eval (useFirebase.js?e6aa:4) at
> Module../src/auth/firebase/useFirebase.js (app.js:1240) at
> **webpack_require** (app.js:854) at fn (app.js:151) at eval (utils.js:7) at Module../src/auth/utils.js (app.js:1252) at
> **webpack_require** (app.js:854) at fn (app.js:151) vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8440 You are running Vue in development mode.
> Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
> See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: Can you please share a part of your code maybe firebaseService.js file etc?

Comment: Please add the above as a code block in your question

Comment: Does this has to do not connected with Firebase? I dont have anything setup in Firebase, this is git clone 
of a project that I am trying to run.


These codes are in useFirebase.js file

import useFirebase from '@core/auth/firebase/useFirebase'
import * as firebaseLib from 'firebase'

const { firebase } = useFirebase(firebaseLib, {})
export default firebase

Comment: did you install firebase sdk tools?

Comment: @Amaarrockz no sorry don't know how to do that, no instruction given

Comment: Can you share the code where you are initializing Firebase?

Comment: Looks like I need to create a firebase app and link to it. Will do and check.